# How to change DataGrid cell background color based on cell value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I'm trying to change the `Background` color of my `DataGrid` cells that contains the word 'Modify'.

In `WinForms` I've accomplished that with this code:

```
DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
style.BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;

foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Row.Cells["Permission"].Value.ToString().Contains("Modify"))
    {
        Row.Cells["Permission"].Style = style;
    }
}
```

I populate this `DataGrid` with a `DataTable`.

I know very little about `WPF` yet, so if you have any suggestions, please be very specific.

Comment: I'm using `dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();` to get the DataTable, but then I got the message "The items collection must be empty before using ItemSource".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following to fix my issue:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="173" Margin="53,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="378" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Selecione}" Header="Selecione"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Grupos}" Header="Grupos"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Permissoes}" Header="Permissões">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Permissoes}" Value="Modify">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>`enter code here`
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: You made it for a column, is it possible to make it for all columns dynamically ?